# Select max(value) and corresponding row without using rownum or limit

Tags: mysql, oracle, ansi-sql

Have a table for teacher with date of joining, need to write a query to find most teacher joined the school and query should display year and no of teacher who joined that year.
I have written the query got the result by using Limit, but is there any other way to write a query.

```
select
  count(teah_id) as no_of_teachers,
  substr(DATE_OF_JOINING,1,4) as year
from teacher
group by substr(DATE_OF_JOINING,1,4)
order by count(phy_id) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is not valid Oracle syntax as far as I know.  Are you using MySQL?

Comment: yes using Mysql. How can write the same query in oracle without usning rownum?

Answer (score 0):

You could put your current query into a CTE and then reuse it to find the highest count:

```
with cte as (
    select
        count(teah_id) as no_of_teachers,
        substr(DATE_OF_JOINING,1,4) as year
    from teacher
    group by substr(DATE_OF_JOINING, 1, 4)
)

select
    year,
    no_of_teachers
from cte
where
    no_of_teachers = (select max(no_of_teachers) from cte);
```